# "Error: Conflicting with its use here as the name of a function" when using += operator

Tags: matlab, syntax-error

File abc.m has

```
function [] = abc(N)
    N += 1;
```

When I try to execute abc by passing any number (e.g. 5) for N, I get the error 
"N" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with its use here as the name of a function. 
It gives the error in the line N += 1;

But I do not understand where I am using N as a function name.

Comment: += is not a defined increment operation in matlab.  Use N = N+1

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is `N = N + 1`, as David points out. However, if you think the error message you get seems strange, I've provided an explanation below.

This has to do with how MATLAB recognizes [command syntax](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html#bqlqlwc). Depending on where you put your spaces, MATLAB interprets commands differently.
Note that you get the same error message for `N +* 1` or `N +*-`

`+=`, `+*-`, `**0` etc, are not correct syntax in MATLAB. Therefore MATLAB must take a guess at what you're attempting to do.

If you didn't have any spaces before `+=`, according to MATLAB it would have to be an operation on variables. You will therefore get the error message: "Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment".

The space in front of `+=` makes this look like either an operation on variables, or an attempt at using  `N` as a function (similar to `ls`, `disp`, `whos` etc).

Normally, the space on both sides of `+=` would mean this was an operation on variables. However, `+=` operator is not on the list of "[Operators and Elementary Operations](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/operators-and-elementary-operations.html)", so that possibility can be ruled out. The only possible valid use of this syntax is if this is a function that can take strings as input.

The syntax is actually correct in some cases (though useless), for instance:

```
whos += 0  %// Gives no errors
```

but:

```
whos = 1;
whos += 1;
??? Error: "whos" was previously used as a variable,
 conflicting with its use here as the name of a function
 or command.
```

So to sum it up: MATLAB sees `N += 1` goes through the list of possibilities and ends up interpreting `N` as a function, since that's the only possible case where it would be a valid syntax.

If you define a function `N` this way, you won't get any error messages:

```
function varargout = N(varargin)
varargout{1} = 'You see, no errors';
end

N += 0
ans =
You see, no errors
```

Answer (score 2):

`N+=1` is not valid Matlab syntax, you have to do `N=N+1`. I believe it is valid Octave syntax though.